# Is there any way to detect Samsung theme being applied?

Tags: android, android-theme, samsung-mobile-sdk

There's an issue with my app's icon when I apply different Samsung Themes from Themes market. I may solve the problem if I can detect a theme. Is there any way to do so programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

lazy way : create night mode drawable for your icons , and then test the themes .